# How do I automated git commits in Java for new files

Tags: java, git

I am trying to include an automated git commit into my Java code.

Currently, my code is producing new files every couple of minutes or hours(depending on different circumstances) and I would like to make a commit whenever a file is created. The java program is supposed to run on a server for several days before finishing, so the commits would have to happen while the program is running.

I assume that I would have to include a certain call of a shell script into my code but so far I didn't find an answer on how to do it properly.

### My question is: How would I get this automated git commit under these circumstances?

Comment: just do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git commit -m ...");` or use libraries like libgitc or jGit.

Comment: You can use [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) for this. JGit is a pure Java implementation of Git.